# SSH into scaled out Azure app service for container

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

How to get access to the specific instance of the scaled out to N instances Azure web app running a Linux container? Portal allows to SSH into one of the existing instances but never tells which one you are in.

Comment: Are you using ASE for scale out your App?

Comment: I am scaling application service plans @WayneYang-MSFT

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Kudu-based web SSH (e.g. https://[appname].scm.[ase-name].p.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host):

There is an "ARRAffinity" cookie used by Kudu to decide what instance to connect to, you can manually change it to force a specific instance, it's a bit cumbersome but it does work, here are the instructions:
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2016/11/21/azure-app-service-how-to-connect-to-the-kudu-site-of-a-specific-instance/